# Google Sheets published on the web continue the calculation even if closed

Tags: excel, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, google-sheets-query

I have an Excel spreadsheet with a huge amount of data to calculate in real time.

I noticed that Google Sheets has the option to publish the spreadsheet online and update it every 1 minute.

My calculations in real time are based on the quotes that are provided by Google Finance. Therefore, each time the quote is updated, the spreadsheet redoes all calculations.

If I publish on the web will it continue to calculate normally even with the browser CLOSED? Is there any better alternative (like a Virtual Machine or the like)?

Comment: Question is, do you need the data in real time, or every one minute, or every time someone opens the sheet will do?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I need the data calculated only once a day. In Excel it takes a long time to calculate them

Comment: Please have a look at [guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Can you be clearer in your question? what exactly are you asking?

Answer (score 0):

### You can turn off automatic updates for published files.

(*I believe this is what you mean*)

When you publish a file, you can choose to stop automatic updates of calculations on the sheet by following the [steps outlined here](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/183965?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en).

Sorry If I misunderstood.

---

Also as a workaround to have the sheet load faster perhaps you might want to try the following:

### You can use a Google Spreadsheet and:

1. Write a bound [Apps Scripts](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference) to do the calculations.
2. [Install a time-driven trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers) to do it when you want it to (daily).
3. Have your script `setValues` into the spreadsheet range(s) that you need.

*Hint: You can use
    [`UrlFetch`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl)
    to get the data from any url.*

---

Since you are using Google finance, there is a built-in formula in sheets already.
[`GOOGLEFINANCE(ticker, attribute, start_date, end_date|num_days, interval)`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093281?hl=en)

---

## Note:

Google sheets run in the cloud, and the sheet itself is not updated unless, it is opened, edited, called from a script, or script trigger, form trigger.

However, you can set up a time-based trigger to run a script and put the data in your sheet, once a day. The script will certainly take the time needed to process its instructions, but it will not be the sheet itself. 
And by using Apps Script you can access all of Google Suite's Services and APIs , including Gmail, Drive, etc.

*You can also have your script write logs that help a lot in debugging.*